# onDateSetListener in DatePickerDialog in Fragment

Tags: android

Hi i was implementing onDatesetListener in Fragment using DatePickerDialog.

```
        class LeaveManagerFragment extends Fragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener



      editText_toDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    clickedEditText = 2;
                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), date, myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    datePickerDialog.setOnDateSetListener(getContext());
                    datePickerDialog.show();
                }
            });

 @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        System.out.println("Date set");
    }
```

I was getting the following error in passing getContext() in `datePickerDialog.setOnDateSetListener(getContext());`

> setOnDateSetListener (android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)
>   in DatePickerDialog cannot be applied to (android.content.Context)

How to implement .ondatesetListener in Fragment?

Comment: You have to pass an `OnDateSetListener` not a context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this change

`datePickerDialog.setOnDateSetListener(LeaveManagerFragment.this);`

It means that your class i.e. the fragment implements the date set listener interface.

Comment: I am getting the following error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setOnDateSetListener(Landroid/app/DatePickerDialog$OnDateSet‌​Listener;)V in class Landroid/app/DatePickerDialog; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.app.DatePickerDialog' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add date :

```
datePickerDialog.setOnDateSetListener(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set OnDateSetListener their but you are giving activity context which does not implements OnDateSetListener, you have to pass your fragment which has implementation of OnDateSetListener as object instead of passing getContext check this:

```
     class LeaveManagerFragment extends Fragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener



            editText_toDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickedEditText = 2;
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),LeaveManagerFragment.this  myCalendar
            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            datePickerDialog.show(); 
            }
        });

       @Override
      public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
       System.out.println("Date set");
   }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setOnDateSetListener(Landroid/app/DatePickerDialog$OnDateSetListener;)V in class Landroid/app/DatePickerDialog; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.app.DatePickerDialog' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-
Instead of

```
datePickerDialog.setOnDateSetListener(getContext());
```

use this

```
datePickerDialog.setOnDateSetListener(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Pass,

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(LeaveManagerFragment.this, date, myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

instead of,

```
 DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```